# python setup.py develop to override installed version

Tags: python, distutils

I have a package I am developing. This package is already installed as an egg file parked in the site-packages directory, egg path added to easy-install.pth.

I now realized I have a bug in the package, so I invoked `python setup.py develop` to hook up the development dir. The path of the source dir is correctly added to easy-install.pth, but it's added latest, meaning that the already installed egg will be chosen and imported first with I issue `import mypackage`.

How can I have the development hook override the already installed package ?

Eventually, if I am doing it wrong, please explain what's the proper strategy to solve this use case.

Comment: Are you using `distutils`? Which version?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using pip,

```
sudo pip uninstall packagename
```

will prompt for all packages that are in the easy-install.pth and delete all of them, upon confirmation.

You can then do a `setup.py develop` so that only the development branch is in the python path.

If you need multiple versions of the same library, the best option is to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (and [virtualenvwrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) as the bash helper).

Also worth mentioning, if you want the simplest solution without any network traffic (I can't imagine why), you might as well, just symlink from the site-packages, like:

```
sudo ln -fs ~/django_registration/registration /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_registration
```

If you are using pip for package installation (why wouldn't you?) you can also get the developing version into the easy-install.pth by something like:

```
pip install -e hg+http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/#egg=django_registration
```

**Update, based on the comment:**

If you want to use the new package only in the current module, you can manually modify the sys.path, like

```
sys.path.insert(1,'/path/to/package')
```

So, the import picks up from the right location.

Comment: The point is that I don't want to remove the stable package. I want to override it, at least for a while. It is not a standard package, it's scrambled, and its installation and use requires a patched python I developed.

Comment: Updated the answer to manually modify the sys.path, for this case.

Comment: I don't have any built package to refer to. I may build it as an egg and then do as you pointed out, but that would defeat the whole point of develop: do changes and see them immediately without rebuilding. The only problem, as I see it, is that develop adds the new entry in easy-install.pth as last entry, not as first, hence the already installed package (which is also in easy-install.pth) is found first.

Comment: You can add the path, that is in the easy-install.pth in the end, on top manually as `sys.path.insert(1,'/path/to/package')` right?

Comment: yes, I definitely can, but I was wondering if this case was expected and there was some magical option that did it for me

Comment: Should be `sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/package')`, right?  Meaning it will become the *first* element in the path.  Just in case your current dir is a different version of the module (since `''` is normally `sys.path[0]`).

Answer (score 3):

You can ask `pip` to override the current installed packages with `--upgrade` and `pip` can install from a local dir so:

```
easy_install pip # if you don't have pip installed
pip install /your/package --upgrade
```

Comment: Should use install -e to install in develop/editable mode, i.e. link instead of copying so that changes in your checkout are seen immediately by your test runner or other Python program.

Comment: OP explains in his comment that *The point is that I don't want to remove the stable package.*

Answer (score 1):

I would use a virtual environment, that is, an isolated Python installation that is not affected by distributions installed system-wide.  See virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on PyPI.